# Is there an easy way in Flex to make a center-aligned label word-wrap in a relatively evened-out way?

Tags: html, css, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

Imagine a label that looks like this:

```
The Name of Some Corporation from Some
                State
```

If you want labels to automatically wrap any text assigned to them in such a way that  would look more like this:

```
     The Name of Some
Corporation from Some State
```

where the lines are much more evened out, is there an easy way to do this?  I've been working on make effectively my own class to do this programmatically, but it's been costing me a lot of time on just researching things.  Maybe there's an easier way?  I wonder about embedding CSS/HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there is not. Word Wrap generally works by fitting as much onto one line as possible and move what can't fit onto the next line. The best you might be able to do is use `justify` instead, which would take up the full width of each line, or decrease the width of the `Label`.

I suppose you could also extend `Label` and add in your own option or rewrite the way Word Wrap occurs, but I would not recommend doing this. I recently tried to write a truncation formula and figuring out where a word is with in a line or what line it is even on is a royal pain in AS3.

Comment: Apparently it turns out listening for `FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE` on the `TextArea`, then pulling its `TextField` out and calling `getLineIndexOfChar()` will let you know where the line breaks are.